# How can I achieve this effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I really like the effect of the blocks moving towards you and slight animation in this effect, this developer seems to be using Mootools, and ideas on how to achieve this or a similar effect in jQuery?

http://ultranoir.com/en/#!/blog/home/

Comment: Have you forgotten to include the link?

Answer (score 1):

He only animates the `margin-left`, `margin-top`, `width` and `height` and sets a higher `z-index` for the block. The shadow is a background image (10px wider and higher than the box without hover). He has a fixed width and height for the boxes.

On hover he enlarges the div by 10px in both dimensions so the shadow background comes visible and also moves the box 10px to top and left.

In jQuery it could be

```
$('#box').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', 200).animate({ 
             marginLeft: '-10px', 
             marginTop: '-10px', 
             width: '+=10', 
             height: '+=10' 
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate( { 
             marginLeft: '0px', 
             marginTop: '0px', 
             width: '-=10', 
             height: '-=10' 
        }, function () { $(this).css('z-index', 0); });
    }
);
```

I could post a fiddle using the background images the author of the page uses, but I think that would be naughty.

Comment: Is he actually even using Javascript for that at all? Is it not just CSS3 transition:s?

Comment: This may be indeed the case, but the OP asked for a jQuery solution.

Comment: I think this won't work correctly. look here http://jsfiddle.net/vyyhq/2/.

Comment: Had a typo, it works http://jsfiddle.net/vyyhq/3/ but as I said it would be naughty to use the background image from the page in a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a box that moves towards you:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7hfK8/

JS:

```
$('#box').animate({
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    left: '0px',
    top: '0px'
});
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    position: absolute;
    width 0px;
    height:0px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use JavaScript?

This effect can be achieved using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/HHRgG/

```
#block{
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 150px;
    width:300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

#block:hover
{
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #000;
}
```

**Edit:** Updated fiddle with CSS transitions to make it *prettier* 
http://jsfiddle.net/HHRgG/1/

Comment: this isn'T so nice as with jquery. that's why jquery exists

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't why jQuery exists...

Comment: simplier, more interactable, animateable

Comment: lol "simplier", your solution requires a download of a JS library, additional script tag, and 14 lines of JavaScript. Mine requires 2 overridden CSS styles and a box shadow...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/RNuEu/7/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', 200).animate({

            marginTop: '-10px',
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({

            marginTop: '0px',

        }, function() {
            $(this).css('z-index', 200);
        });
    })
});
</script>
<style>
#box {
    position: absolute;
    width 30px;
    height:60px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
<div id="box">test</div>
```