# Where can I research information regarding this advance 'scroll to page'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I have found a website feature that I really like. I'm still fairly new to front end web development and I can't find any information regarding what the scrolling technique is used [here](http://www.newjumoconcept.com/en/#home).

It's the 'page to page' scrolling I'm interested in, all I require is the name of the technique so I can research and self learn.

Thank you!

Comment: You can find that page in the list of sites using fullpage.js https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#who-is-using-fullpagejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's the name of this "page to page scroll" effect, but when you scroll at the beginning of the page there is a **parallax effect** used on the desktop lamp.

Also, the library to do the "page to page scroll" effect is **fullPage.js** and it's located here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

You can see those related questions on SO: [How can I achieve this background scroll effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10269209/827168) and [Differential scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9359311/827168)

Edit: quoting myself from linked post to have complete answer:

> - a great demo from Nike http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/
> - a collection of parallax http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/21-examples-of-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design
>     (make sure to see each example, some are really great ! ex:
>     http://benthebodyguard.com/index.php  http://www.siebennull.com/ 
>     http://janploch.de/)
> - Mercedez Class A web site http://a-class.mercedes-benz.com/com/en/index.html#!/?s=live (not
>     really parallax but still great)
> - a tutorial on how to make an image slider using parallax effect http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/01/03/parallax-slider/
> - another tutorial with different effects http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/
> - a library to do parallax https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax
> - another library https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js
>
> You may also like this:
>
> - http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/
> - http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Answer (score 2):

It's the latest technique in web design, called

## Parallax Scrolling

- With new technologies like HTML5 and CSS3, it's becoming possible to create more advanced, interesting and remarkable effects in the browser.
- One big web design trend of the moment is parallax scrolling, which involves the background moving at a slower rate to the foreground, creating a 3D effect as you scroll down the page.

---

## Useful Links

- [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)
- [Simple Tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [46 great examples of parallax scrolling websites](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/parallax-scrolling-1131762)

---

Comment: I came across parallax scrolling in my search after seeing it in spotify (and fell in love). Thank you for sharing those informative links, however I am after the 'scroll and it takes you all the way to the next page. It locks the scroller so you can't 'free-scroll'. Sorry for my lack of knowledge to describe the issue and thank you!

Comment: Thanks ! However, the other answer targeted the core issue of page to page scrolling with the library link. I appreciate your help too

Comment: Okay no problem ! Peace!